# Swift: How to implement User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am implementing a custom "chooser" toolbar, like the iOS equivalent of a radio button set (`UISegmentedControl`). Just a horizontal bar divided into options.

To do this, I created a subclass of `UIControl` called `SegmentedControl` and implemented custom drawing. However, with such a view, I need the option to set what the available options are. I could have just accessed the view from the controller's `viewDidLoad()` and set those there, but I like using the interface builder for that kind of stuff.

So I discovered this wonderful thing called "User Defined Runtime Attributes." I created a `String` attribute with a key `buttonValues` and set a value (this is a simple Male/Female chooser so I went with "Male|Female"). I found out that you can access these values using the function `self.valueForKey()` and pass in the key. I made a parser to turn that string into an array and then added functionality for the `drawRect()` function to use the array to set up the buttons.

**When I ran the app, I got an error about "Key Value Coding-compliance."**

So I looked that up, and I found out that the class has to have backing variables to store the attributes. So fine, I added an instance variable called `buttonValues` and initialized it to `""`. Now the app runs fine but the value comes out empty from the `self.valueForKey()` function. I looked up tutorials on how to set up user defined runtime attributes but they don't go into enough detail. They talk about Key Value Coding-compliance like it's something I should just know.

I would like to know exactly what I must do for this to work properly, *in gory detail*.

Answer (score 28):

For your purposes you can use either user-defined runtime attributes or expose your class and properties as editable in Interface Builder. Either way, you'll want to declare your properties as implicitly unwrapped Optional variables -- `IBOutlets` are created the same way. If you need to make other changes once your properties have a value, give them `didSet` property observers. The properties will be at their default value during initialization (or `nil` if no default was set) and set when the view is added to a superview.

### User Defined Runtime Attributes

This works more or less like you've described above -- here's the simplest version:

```
class LabeledView : UIView {
    var viewLabel: String! {
    didSet {
        println("didSet viewLabel, viewLabel = \(self.viewLabel)")
    }
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println("init with coder, viewLabel = \(self.viewLabel)")
    }
}
```

Then set the `viewLabel` attribute to "Hello" on the view in your storyboard, like so:

[image: Xcode panel showing user-defined runtime attributes]

When you build & run, the console will show that the property is being set correctly:

```
init with coder, viewLabel = nil
didSet viewLabel, viewLabel = Hello
```

### @IBDesignable & @IBInspectable

This gives your custom view a much nicer interface in IB -- set the `@IBDesignable` attribute on your class and `@IBInspectable` attributes on each property. Here's the same class:

```
@IBDesignable class LabeledView : UIView {
    @IBInspectable var viewLabel: String!

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Now you can set your inspectable properties at the top of the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder:

[image: Attributes Inspector with inspectable property]

Comment: You shouldn’t have to use user-defined runtime attributes. Use `IB_DESIGNABLE` and `IBInspectable` to expose attributes with proper UI. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html).

Comment: I wasn't thinking to use implicitly unwrapped optionals. I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg is right -- see my additional comments

Comment: So yea, IBDesignable and IBInspectable are awesome. Not only can you edit class properties as shown above, you can actually pre-render your custom views (custom drawing included) in IB without having to run your app. See [this](http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/).

Comment: It can be a custom enum?

Comment: As a comment on @DanielG.R. , I wanted also to have a custom enum but it is not working so the simplest solution I found is to have the var defined as String! and then have an enum with raw values String and in the viewDidAppear to check if the var is not among the enum. If it is not I show an alert. Obviously these errors should not happen.

Comment: hi nate, your answers really help me a lot, theres still one problem left though. When i call the runtime attribute with just didst, it still get the nil value, after that then comes the value, so my Xcode keep getting null pointer before the real value comes.

Comment: when i was using this i was using the Number type, in your code though i thought it would map to a swift `Int` but it will crash on that, you have to use `NSNumber` instead

Comment: apparently this doesn't work any more in Xcode 10/Swift 4.2: `Failed to set (url) user defined inspected property on (MyApp.ViewController): [<MyApp.ViewController 0x7f813620a591> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key url.`

Comment: are we just gonna shut up about how buggy IBDesignables & IBInspectable are? not saying it's a bad idea, just asking

Comment: I'm going crazy because interface builder lags constantly even with "Automatically Refresh Designables" off. I can tell it's caused by IBInspectables because turning them off or just not being on the Inspectable tab allows me to use interface builder without lag.

What am I doing wrong? I Just want to use IBDesignables without intense lag.

Comment: For UDRA you need to add @objc to your property definition now (if it's not IBInspectable). It used to be that Xcode did this implicitly, but that's no longer the case