# Failed to set () user defined inspected property on (UIButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, user-defined

In a simple ViewController, I added one UIButton.
I would like to use "User Defined Runtime Attributes". For now I added the default Bool attribute.

[image: screen]

The button is an @IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet var button:UIButton!
```

The link in the storyboard is done.

I have nothing else in my app.

I got this error:

```
2017-03-26 20:31:44.935319+0200 ISAMG[357:47616] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): 
[<UIButton 0x15e3a780> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
```

I don't understand what I'm missing.

EDIT 1

Following the advices @timaktimak, I created a custom UIButton class:

```
@IBDesignable
class ChoiceButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var keyPath: Bool! {
        didSet {
            print("didSet viewLabel, viewLabel = \(self.keyPath)")
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)  {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
}
```

[image: screen2]

The error is the same:

```
2017-03-26 22:32:27.389126+0200 ISAMG[429:71565] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (ISAMG.ChoiceButton): 
[<ISAMG.ChoiceButton 0x14e8f040> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, your button doesn't have a property called `keyPath` to be setting it to something.

User Defined Runtime Attributes are used to simply set a property value in the Interface Builder.

You can use a standard property that every `UIButton` has, for example `backgroundColor`:

[image]

Or, you can create a custom `UIButton` subclass, add a property to it, then set the button's class to the created custom subclass and set the property value in the User Defined Runtime Attributes section.

You can check out, for example, this answer, it contains an example of a custom class with User Defined Runtime Attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24433125/3445458

**Edit:** make sure you are not using optional (or implicitly unwrapped optional) for the type, it doesn't work with User Defined Runtime Attributes (I guess because the Interface Builder doesn't know whether the value can be set to nil, and so show it in the options or not).

So you can't do

```
var keyPath: Bool!
```

instead you can only do

```
var keyPath: Bool = false
```

or don't use a default value and set it in the constuctor instead. For some reason it works with an optional `String` (and in the example they use an optional `String`), but it doesn't with optional `Bool`. To conclude, don't use or worry about User Defined Runtime Attributes too much, it is clearer to set the default values in code!

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 28):

Since this thread came up about 5 times in my search for a solution, I wanted to post my fix here for future frustrated souls. The reason I kept getting this error is because Interface Builder doesn't clean up old IBInspectable properties if you're experimenting with them.

In my case, I started with an Int property called `type` and set a few custom buttons on my screen to use a value of 3 as a test. Later, I changed it to a more meaningful property name and made it a string, then set a few of those. But when I ran the app, I was getting this message.

I didn't discover the error until I went to the Identity Inspector and noticed that I still had an old keypath and value in use for some of the buttons:

[image]

Removing the old keypath fixed the problem.

Comment: PS I know this doesn't directly address OP's question. Just posting here as a public service since Google thinks this is the only viable place for it.

Comment: Great answer, by the way what do we learn with this?
**Don't use** `@IBInspectable` in prototype(test/experimenting/or whatever) versions, let to add that to the properties only when your project or component are finished.

Thanks man

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed after removing not needed anymore property from prototype.

Answer (score 1):

In User Defined Runtime Attributes use `layer.cornerRadius` instead of `cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like failed to set `keyPath` bool value to true of false.
setKeyPath to true or false!

Answer (score 0):

**Compare** **@IBInspectable**(in sub class) and **Key Path**(identity inspector). Remove key value which is not in @IBInspectable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set the set a property value in the Interface Builder is that create an IBOutlet of your view on your view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourView: UIView!


yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = false
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```