# Crash on setting user defined property for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to set localization strings for UIButton in interface builder, so I did the following :

1- Create a category to add the needed function:

**.h**

```
@interface UIButton (Localization)

- (void)setLocalizeKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "UIButton+Localization.h"

@implementation UIButton (Localization)

- (void)setLocalizeKey:(NSString *)key {
    [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(key, nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

2- use the property in interface builder

[image]

Now when I run the project I got the following error!:

> Failed to set (localizeKey) user defined inspected property on
>   (UIButton): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key localizeKey.

What is the problem??

Comment: It's may be an issue of caching 
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53587148/3122406

Comment: I have checked and its working fine.

Comment: I also did a quick test with no problems. Is it possible you created the `UIButton+Localization` category, but did not add it to the target?

Comment: @DonMag Thank you so much! That was the issue!!